# Multiple font colours in a single row in a JList

Tags: java, swing, fonts, colors, jlist

I am creating an application in which we show a couple hundred records in a JList.

Occasionally, we would want to highlight certain values in each record with a different font colour.

I have tried using HTML which works perfectly, although this would go horribly wrong if any of these records contained any sort of html tags, as they would be rendered.

Unforunately you can't have:

```
normaltext<html><font color="red">redtext</font></html>
```

as it seems the HTML has to be at the beginning.

I have tried overriding the getListCellRendererComponent, where I can create a JPanel, and have a JLabel for each part of the record with a different foreground colour, but this is inefficient for large records.

I'd rather not use any third party solutions due to licensing issues.

Does anyone have any solutions for this scenario?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have tried using HTML which works perfectly, although this would go
>   horribly wrong if any of these records contained any sort of html
>   tags, as they would be rendered.

Actually if the text contains html tags you can escape the tags and wrap it in `<html> escaped text of record</html>` marking text wth desired colors

UPDATE working example

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame f=new JFrame();
    String text="<html>An example of tag &lt;html&gt; with <font color='red'>&lt;input&gt;</font> tag colored</html>";
    f.add(new JLabel(text));
    f.pack();
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: Yeah I just thought about that, would I just need to escape <,>,&?

Comment: it depends on formatting you have. There are multiple libraries e.g. https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html